# Matlab error Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab

I have a program that is composed of 2 groups of radiobutton for each radiobutton i have an edit box next to it.

The goal of this program is when a radiobutton is selected (2 button can be selected at the same time if they belong to different groups) to enable the edit box that is next to it (the edit box of non selected buttons are all off)

To do this i have the following program

```
     function fig=exemple1
    fig = figure('Units','normalized');
    uibgA = uibuttongroup(fig,'Position',[0,0.5,0.5,0.5],'Title','ButtonGroupA')
    uibgB = uibuttongroup(fig,'Position',[0,0.0,0.5,0.5],'Title','ButtonGroupB')
    uipA = uipanel(fig,'Position',[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],'Title','Group A')
    uipB = uipanel(fig,'Position',[0.5,0.0,0.5,0.5],'Title','Group B')
    grpARadioLabels = {
        'Choice 1','Tooltip 1'
        'Choice 2','Tooltip 2'
        'Choice 3','Tooltip 3'
        };
    grpBRadioLabels = {
        'Choice 1','Tooltip 1'
        'Choice 2','Tooltip 2'
        'Choice 3','Tooltip 3'
        'Choice 4','Tooltip 4'
        };
    for i = 3:-1:1
        rbA(i) = uicontrol(uibgA,'Style','radiobutton',...
            'String',grpARadioLabels{i,1},...
            'TooltipString',grpARadioLabels{i,2},...
            'Position',[10,10+i*22,200,22] ...
            )
        
        prmsA{i} = uicontrol(uipA,'Style','edit',...
            'Position',[10,10+i*22,100,22],...
            'Tag',grpARadioLabels{i,1},...
            'Enable','off',...
            'String',sprintf('param %d',i))
    end
    for i = 4:-1:1
        rbB(i) = uicontrol(uibgB,'Style','radiobutton',...
            'String',grpBRadioLabels{i,1},...
            'TooltipString',grpBRadioLabels{i,2},...
            'Position',[10,10+i*22,200,22] ...
            )
        prmsB{i} = uicontrol(uipB,'Style','edit',...
            'Position',[10,10+i*22,100,22],...
            'Tag',grpBRadioLabels{i,1},...
            'Enable','off',...
            'String',sprintf('param %d',i))
    end
set(uibgA,'SelectionChangeFcn',@(o,e)bgChangeFcn(o,e,prmsA))
set(uibgB,'SelectionChangeFcn',@(o,e)bgChangeFcn(o,e,prmsB))
    end
    
    function bgChangeFcn(src,event,prms)
    allprms = [prms{:}];
    set(allprms,'Enable','off');
    lbl = event.NewValue.String;
    set(findobj(allprms,'Tag',lbl),'Enable','on');
    end
```

but when i launch it i have this error :

```
    Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in exemple1>bgChangeFcn (line 56)
lbl = event.NewValue.String;

Error in exemple1>@(o,e)bgChangeFcn(o,e,prmsA) (line 49)
set(uibgA,'SelectionChangeFcn',@(o,e)bgChangeFcn(o,e,prmsA))

Error in hgfeval (line 63)
        feval(fcn{1},varargin{:},fcn{2:end});

Error in uitools.uibuttongroup/childAddedCbk>manageButtons (line 80)
    hgfeval(cbk, source, evdata);
 
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

if anyone could help me understand why i have this error (I use matlab 2012) it would help a lot

Comment: The error is rather clear: either `event` or `event.NewValue` is not a structure, so you cannot dot-index into it. What does `whos event` and `whos event.NewValue` return?

Comment: 'event.NewValue' is supposed to get the tag of the new selected radiobutton as the edit box and the radiobutton have the same tag so that in the next line the we can enable the edit box

Comment: Sure, but apparently it's not a structure, as I said.

Comment: event.NewValue is a struct it's event.NewValue.String that is not.

Comment: Turn on the debugger to stop at an error (type `dbstop if error` on the MATLAB prompt, you can also do this through the UI somehow), then run your program. When you hit that point, the debugger will show you the code at the line where the error is happening. You will be able to examine the values of each of the variables. See what `event` and/or `event.NewValue` actually are, one of them likely doesn't match your expectation. This is where you backtrack and try to figure out why your expectation is wrong. This is how you fix your program and how you improve your programming skills. Good luck!

Comment: So i managed to find the error on newer version of matlab my fonction work. But on the older version that i use (Maltab 2012) you can't call <event.NewValue.String> you need to get it with : <get(event.NewValue,'String')>